# PHP exec() not returning error message in output

Tags: php, xml, svn, exec

I am trying to get certain output for svn command in XML format. Output is ok when I type valid parameters. However, when I type in wrong password, output does not show error message.
This is the PHP code:

```
exec('/usr/bin/svn --username something --password something --non-interactive log -r HEAD --xml --verbose http://a51.unfuddle.com/svn/a51_activecollab/', $output);
```

Here is output I get in the terminal:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://a51.unfuddle.com/svn/a51_activecollab': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://a51.unfuddle.com)
```

And here is the output I get from the $output variable with var_dump:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(21) "<?xml version="1.0"?>"
[1]=>
string(5) "<log>"
}
```

As you can see the $output variable does not return third line of output, where terminal does. Please help me to get the same output as I get in terminal (I even tried with shell_exec() or system() methods but they return the same output as exec()) How do I get full output? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to capture the `stderr` too.

Redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` should do the trick. Append `2>&1` to the end of your command.

e.g.

```
exec("/usr/bin/svn --username something --password something --non-interactive log -r HEAD --xml --verbose http://a51.unfuddle.com/svn/a51_activecollab/ 2>&1", $output);
```

If it is a *complex* command (e.g. one with a pipe, like doing a mysqldump and passing it to gzip and then redirecting to file `mysqldump ... | gzip > db.sql.gz`) create a subshell to capture the overall standard-error and redirect it to standard-output:

```
exec('( error_command | cat >/dev/null ) 2>&1', $output)
#     ^                                ^   ^
#     `-- sub-shell with the command --´   `-- stderr to $output
```

Comment: Aside: isn't it bizarre that PHP's exec doesn't provide a simple way to capture the `stderr` output separately?

Comment: @StephenC: It may appear so on first sight, however it makes more sense when understanding why there are two different streams firsthand ([some folklore](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11499)) and then knowing that PHP has a SAPI and error handling. E.g. in CLI when you execute that code, you directly see errors in your terminal - regardless of the output the program needs to process. Or if it's running within php-fpm, you get the error reporting in your server logs. Not such a bad default running a system.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably not the solution, just a bad suggestion : have you tried to add an extra echo in the command:

```
exec('/usr/bin/svn --username something --password something --non-interactive log -r HEAD --xml --verbose http://a51.unfuddle.com/svn/a51_activecollab/;**echo ""**', $output);
```

And the other way to solve that is as already mentionned : if you don't have the last line in the $output, it is in the returned value of the exec() function anyway.
You'd have then

```
$totalOutput = push($msg,$output);
```

with

```
$msg = exec('/usr/bin/svn --username something --password something --non-interactive log -r HEAD --xml --verbose http://a51.unfuddle.com/svn/a51_activecollab/', $output);
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to define a variable in which to store the message

`$msg = exec('/usr/bin/svn --username something --password something --non-interactive log -r HEAD --xml --verbose http://a51.unfuddle.com/svn/a51_activecollab/');`