# Running 'git pull' using shell_exec in PHP not displaying error

Tags: php, git, shell-exec

I'm creating a deployment script for github, written in PHP. I'm using the `shell_exec`command to run `git pull` which works fine.

My issue occurs when there is an error with the pull. If I do it in Terminal, I get the full error. For example:

```
git pull origin master
Updating f706749..8468d24
test.txt: needs update
error: Entry 'test.txt' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

But when I run the same command in `shell_exec` the output is truncated to just

```
Updating f706749..8468d24
test.txt: needs update
```

The error message is getting cut off, possibly because it's a response from the previous response. Is there a way to return the full output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

10-1 the missing lines are not written to **stdout** but to **stderr**.

In that case you can redirect the **stderr** to **stdout** with

```
"command    2>&1"
```

The **2>&1** redirects the error messages to the normal output file.

Comment: Amazing, I wasn't aware of stdout and stderr. That's fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By searching a bit, I might have found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863699/php-exec-not-returning-error-message-in-output-when-executing-svn-command) to your problem.

Try capturing stderr.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the error to your output. In the exec command use 2> which is the "standard error" stream.