# How to get output from executable file in php

Tags: php

I can't get output from executable file (a.out) via php. 
my php code is :

```
$file = "/path/main.cpp";
$command="cd $path && c++ -lm ".$file;
exec($command);
$output = exec("cd $path && ./a.out");
exec("cd $path && ./a.out > res.txt");
var_dump($output);
```

all commands is executed but, I'm getting empty value;

```
exec("cd $path && ./a.out > res.txt");
```

this command also executed, res.txt was created in folder, but empty file.
How to solve this problem?
My OS is CentOS 7

Comment: Seems like you want [`popen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php).

Comment: Regarding the "empty file" from the redirection, are you sure that the program actually generates any output? Or that the compilation succeeded and the `a.out` program existing?

Comment: yes, I check from terminal, it's ok but via php no output

Comment: Try capturing the error output as well, see if it's failing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863699/php-exec-not-returning-error-message-in-output).

Comment: I get this:
sh: ./a.out: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the output of a command with PHP, you can use the [`shell_exec`](https://php.net/shell_exec) function:

> **shell_exec**
>
> shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output
>   as a string

So, try this:

```
$output = shell_exec("cd $path && ./a.out");
```

Comment: sh: ./a.out: Permission denied

Comment: @BakhodirIsmatov so the problem is another... when you resolve it, `shell_exec` will do what you need

Comment: can apache  run a.out ?

Comment: @BakhodirIsmatov try to run it from terminal if you can, otherwise try to run this in `shell_exec`: `echo shell_exec('echo "it works";');`. Because I don't know what does `a.out` contain, I can't help you on that.