# php not able to execute system commands

Tags: php, shell, exec

For some reason, the following php script when called via apache, is not returning results...  is there a system security setting in php.ini somewhere to allow system commands?

```
<div style="background:#000;color:#fff">
<?php

   $cmd = "/bin/date";
   $output = system($cmd);
   printf("System Output: $output\n");
   exec($cmd, $results);
   printf("Exec Output: {$results[0]}\n");
   echo"<pre>";
   echo system('/bin/ls');
   echo"</pre>";
   ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: I have checked php.ini, disable_functions= is blank.

Comment: What is returning nothing? `system´ or `exec` or both?

Comment: neither.....  Also system is on plesk... :)

Comment: You should first look into similar questions like yours (see the Realated column on the right and on top there is a search box). There can be numerous reasons why these commands "do not work" (in fact they work, but they don't do what you expect - but they work fine!). Also think about how you can debug your problem (your code looks like you started debugging already). Additionally, contact your system administrator, she/he should be able to help you as well. And enable error reporting with PHP, there is safe-mode and such.

Comment: it appears safe mode is on... via phpinfo.php.  Does anyone know how to turn off safe mode in plesk?  in php.ini it says safe mode off ...

Comment: Please learn about the basics of PHP configuration, e.g. see: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php - Please see as well: [PHP: exec() error responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345794/php-exec-error-responses)

Answer (score 1):

Your host (or configuration) is probably restricting system() or exec() command. Check your configuration or contact your host

```
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://php.net/disable-functions
disable_functions =
```

should be blank, works on my machine

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/e47f7

Also, check that SElinux and Suhoshin is configured properly

Comment: guys, selinux is disabled... how come is this happening?

Comment: also seeing sh: /date: No such file or directory
sh: /date: No such file or directory
sh: /ls: No such file or directory in apache logs

Answer (score 0):

plesk safe mode... disabled in httpd.include... sigh... love it when systems land in your lap