# Why I cannot run ifconfig with phpexec

Tags: php

```
$command='ifconfig';
echo $command;
exec($command,$avaialableIPs);
print_r($avaialableIPs);
$command='ls -l';
echo $command;
exec($command,$avaialableIPs);
print_r($avaialableIPs);
```

This is what I got:

The ifconfig command fail but the regular ls-l command works.

I just want to know the avaailable IPs for my server so my curl can use other IP too. I can use ls.

```
ifconfigArray
(
)
ls -lArray
(
    [0] => total 1692
...
    )
    testArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you the server administrator?  If so, check your php.ini.

It may contain something like this:

```
disable_functions=
```

Make sure it's blank.

Refer to: [php not able to execute system commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600815/php-not-able-to-execute-system-commands)

Comment: /etc/php.ini in most linux servers