# Sending value from R to php

Tags: php, r

I have this code in the .php file:

```
$nb1 = 1;
$nb2 = 2;
exec("C:/xampp/phpR/plotR.r $nb1 $nb2", $response);
echo $response;
```

And I have in the .r file:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
x<-args[1]+args[2]
print(x)
```

The php code prints "array" on browser. It should print "3". It prints "array". Where are the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Not even sure what R is so can't comment on what it should return, but in your PHP try print_r($response) instead of echo $response and it'll print the array structure so you can see what it is.

Comment: hello Papillon, nop, the code receive a empty array. In fact i've use print_r() and var_dump()

Answer (score 0):

PHP is interpreting the response from your R script as an array, whether the R script is actually returning an array I'm not sure. Regardless, if you do `var_dump($response)` you'll likely get something like

```
array (size=1)
  0 => int 3
```

I think you should be able to substitute `echo $response[0];` for `echo $response;` and get the results you need.

Comment: hi Aleatoric, the array is empty.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your R script then. Does it print the expected output when you run in from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else happens upon this unanswered question, I had the same problem, and it turned out to be a permissions issue. The user that my webserver was running as didn't have permission to run my R script.

This can be diagnosed by following the excellent directions at:
[How to retrieve PHP exec() error responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345794/how-to-retrieve-php-exec-error-responses)
and viewing the error.

To get things to work nicely, I also changed the output of my R script from `print(x)` to `write(x, stdout())`. While `print(x)` would give you `[1] 3` as an output, `write(x)` would return `3`.